# AutoIt: Why can't I insert an element into an array using a function?

Tags: autoit

When I call the Bar function, the element is not inserted into the array passed as an argument.
Here is my code:

```
Foo ()


Func Foo ()

    Local $Baz[100] = []

    Call ("Bar", $Baz)

    MsgBox (0, "", $Baz[0])

    Return

EndFunc


Func Bar ($_Array)

    $_Array[0] = 1

    Return

EndFunc
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A function handles a "shadow copy" of the parameter (variable or array), unless you use `ByRef` (to tell the function to use/manipulate the given variable directly):

```
Foo ()

Func Foo ()
    Local $Baz[100] = []
    Bar($Baz)
    MsgBox (0, "", $Baz[0])
    Return
EndFunc

Func Bar (ByRef $_Array)
    $_Array[0] = 1
    Return
EndFunc
```

This doesn't work with `call` though.